# Proper logging from a nuget library

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I'm developing a nuget library that is consumable from a WPF app and UWP app, and I want to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` to provide users a way to plug in their logger of choice from their apps (Serilog, NLog, etc..). Therefore I've begun with this:

```
public static partial class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    internal static ILogger _logger;

    public static void AttachLogger(ILogger logger) => _logger = logger;
.
.
.
}
```

In this case, I need to add logging to extension methods based on FrameworkElement. I feel I'm going about this the wrong way since I have a function called `AttachLogger` to inject a logger, and also my `ILogger` is not associated with a type (ex: `ILogger<T>`) since I'm in a static class.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see better way to "inject" dependency into static class with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` other than using dedicated method for it (`AttachLogger` in your case).

Regarding generic `Logger<T>`, you could inject `ILoggerFactory` and create logger associated to your class

```
public static void AttachLogger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(FrameworkElementExtensions));
}
```

Comment: I did not think of that, thanks I`ll try it out!   :)